# Flask-Sqlalchemy, multiple databases with bind and foreign keys

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have set up an application using `flask`, and a few models using `Flask-SQLAlchemy`. I want to store a few JSON-objects into a separate database, as this database will not be frequently read, only written to. Other data is stored in the main-database.

This works fine, except I would like to set up a relationsship between a table in the JSON-database, and the main-database. If I keep the tables in the same database, this works great(by commenting out `__bind_key__ = 'forms'`), but as I said, I would like to have the databases separate.

I've tried looking at various solutions to this, among other related posts here on StackOverflow. I am clearly doing something wrong.

Currently i get this error, when running `python models.py`:

```
(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "filled_form_data" does not exist
 sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "filled_form_data" does not exist
[SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE filled_form_modified    (\n\tid SERIAL NOT NULL, \n\tdate TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, \n\tfilled_form_data_id INTEGER, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tUNIQUE (id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(filled_form_data_id) REFERENCES filled_form_data (id)\n)\n\n']
```

I'm thinking I would need to specify the database somehow in there also, but I though `sqlalchemy` would do that for me. I am a bit confused by the documantation-page here: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/binds/

I would really appreciate your help on this.

## models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
db = SQLAlchemy()



class FilledFormData(db.Model):
    """Table of json-data for forms."""
    __bind_key__ = 'forms'
    __tablename__ = 'filled_form_data'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    request_form = db.Column(db.JSON)  # All data from the users-form
    form_data = db.Column(db.JSON)  # All data actually used to fill the pdf.


class FilledFormModified(db.Model):
    """Table of modification-dated for FilledForm-model."""
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    filled_form_data_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(FilledFormData.id))
    filled_form_data = db.relationship(
        FilledFormData, primaryjoin='FilledFormModified.filled_form_data_id==FilledFormData.id')  # noqa
    info = {'bind_key': 'forms'}




app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres:///varmekabler'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'products': 'postgres:///vk_products',
    'forms': 'postgres:///vk_forms'
}
db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():

    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
```

Comment: it seems that you have not created tables, call function `create_all()`?

Comment: @Tiny.D yeah, I did. Just did it in another file. I'll update the question to reflect it.

Comment: The issue is FilledFormModified is in the engine (`varmekabler`) and trying to build a foreign key constraint that references an external database (`vk_forms`), which is not possible in most RDBMS. The easy way is to ensure the tables exist in the same database; otherwise, I'm not sure how to solve this here, but first would be to alter `filled_form_data_id` definition (remove the `db.ForeignKey()` portion)